# Easiest way to move from Ubuntu to Windows?

Tags: windows, system-installation, windows-8, backup

For my study next year, my computer *has to* run Windows. It's a requirement. Right now, I want to get used to it a little more, so I plan on installing Windows preemptively.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04, though originally my laptop came with Windows 8 installed. I believe this means that my activation code or whatever is stored within the BIOS(?). I do not own a CD with Windows 8(.1) on it.
I have a 250GB external hard drive -- more than enough to store all my files.

Now, my question is, what is the easiest and safest way to switch to Windows 8(.1), while keeping all my files?

I've tried dual-booting in the past, but it didn't work out for me.

I thought of this plan:

- First I'd copy my entire Home folder to my external hard drive.
- Meanwhile, I'd search the PirateBay or KickassTorrents for a copy of
  Windows 8(.1) (this is legal in my home country: I'm allowed to
  download anything I've technically paid for)
- Then I'd burn that copy to a CD or DVD
- Then boot up from the disk and tell it to erase all data and install
  Windows
- Lastly, I'd reallocate all my files from my hard drive to my laptop

Is this a reasonable plan of action? 
I'm extremely afraid I forgot an essential step or am planning to do something that simply is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the activation code from BIOS with some help from [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/where-do-i-find-the-windows-8-product-key-when-it/d4c5c0c1-825d-47f2-9bed-d9625c7e68ff).

Your general approach is fine, but to be really sure to not loose anything, I'd just make space for a windows partition and try to keep your current install. Have a look [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) and try to adapt it to your situation.

Comment: I think I'm going to try a VirtualBox first, like the others advised me to. But holy damn thanks for all the information and links, truly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You general idea works, but you should really try to find your original Windows license key. Maybe also check if your university has an MSDN Academic Alliance (MSDNAA) or Dreamspark program. There you can usually download the correct (newest) Windows and also get a valid license key. Using a license key that isn't yours is asking for trouble when it comes to using Windows update, as other people have probably also used the same key.

The other possibility is to run Windows inside VirtualBox: I've set Windows to use 4GB of RAM and 3 CPU cores and even heavier things like Photoshop work totally fine. The only thing that does not work is 3D heavy applications like games and probably CAD software (although I haven't tried).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though it is, in fact, my license key. I just heard somewhere it gets automatically stored in your BIOS. At least, it worked once before.

Comment: Just as a reference: I had to enable 3D acceleration, but disable 2D acceleration in VirtualBox to get acceptable performance. Also, resuming VirtualBox snapshots doesn't work on my computer if I use more than 1 virtual CPU for Windows, I have no idea why (I always have to shutdown Windows inside VBox instead of just closing VirtualBox and letting it save the state). But that's a minor annoyance.